# Document not save in database using mongoDB Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    password: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

This is controller

```
const User = require("../model/user.model");

const signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, email, password } = req.body;
  const data = User({
    name: name,
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });

  try {
    await data.save();
    res.status(200).json("Data Submitted");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(401).json("Failed");
  }
};

module.exports = signup;
```

Anyone can help me to solve this error
When I test my API from Insomnia this error can occured
Document not save in database using mongoDB Mongoose
Anyone have any idea about that please answer

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, you've defined the `password` field as a `Number`, but in your controller, you are receiving a `String` for the `password`.

Update your Mongoose schema to define the `password` field as a `String`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
//password: {
//  type: Number,
//  required: true,
//},
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
   },
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```